# identify records that make up 90% of total

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a report that identifies key drivers of an overall number/trend.  I would like to automate the functionality to be able to list/identify the underlying records based on a percentage of that number.  For example if the net change for sales of widgets in the south(region) is -5,000.00, but there are positives and negatives- I would like to identify at least ~90% (-4,500.00) of all underlying drivers that make up that -5,000.00 total from largest to smallest.

```
data

region    OfficeLocation  sales
South     1                -500
South     2                300
South     3                -1000
South     4                -2000
South     5                 300
South     6                -700
South     7                -400
South     8                 800
North     11                300
North     22               -400
North     33                1000
North     44                800
North     55                900
North     66                -800
```

for South, the total sales is -3200.  I would like to identify/list the drivers that make up at least 90% of this move(in descending order)- so 90% of -3200 would be 2880.  And the directional moves/sales for South office 3 & 4 = -3000 would be the output for this request:

```
region    OfficeLocation  sales
South     3                -1000
South     4                -2000
```

for North, the total sales is +1800.  I would like to identify/list the drivers that make up at least 90% of this move(in descending order)- so at least 90% of 1800 would be 1620.  And the directional moves/sales for South office 3 & 4 = -3000 would be the output for this request:

region    OfficeLocation  sales
    North     33                1000
    North     44                800

Dataset above has both positive and negative trends for south/north.  Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What would be the expected output for the `'North'` group, for which the sum of sales is positive?

Comment: ^ is an important point. 3 and 4 didn't make up 90% of the gross movement, only the net result

Comment: That is correct, this report is just trying to identify the key drivers that fit the net movement.  I think my example, was poorly created.  In reality, the gross number is dramatically larger where the underlying movers make up much smaller portions of the overall net movement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, it isn't clear what to do in the `'North'` case as the sum is positive there, but ignoring that, you could do something like the following:

```
In [200]: df[df.groupby('region').sales.apply(lambda g: g <= g.loc[(g.sort_values().cumsum() > 0.9*g.sum()).idxmin()])]
Out[200]:
   region  OfficeLocation  sales
2   South               3  -1000
3   South               4  -2000
13  North              66   -800
```

If, in the positive case, you want to find as few elements as possible that together have the property that they make up 90% of the sum of the sales, the above solution can be adopted as follows:

```
def is_driver(group):
    s = group.sum()
    if s > 0:
        group *= -1
        s *= -1
    a = group.sort_values().cumsum() > 0.9*s
    return group <= group.loc[a.idxmin()]

In [168]: df[df.groupby('region').sales.apply(is_driver)]
Out[168]:
   region  OfficeLocation  sales
2   South               3  -1000
3   South               4  -2000
10  North              33   1000
12  North              55    900
```

Note that in the case of a tie, only one element is picked out.

Comment: fuglede, thank you for your help!  i guess what i intended to say, but didn't was- i would like the results for north and south to be separate where we are able to find the largest drivers that explain the net movement for south and the largest drivers that explain the net movement for north

Comment: So in the `'North'` case, you want to find enough positive ones to make up for 90% of the positive result? If so, why is it 800 and not 900 in the example you added?

Comment: fuglede- my apologies, lack of sleep- this is amazing!  thank you so much, you are a genius!