# Identify products that make up 80% of total

Tags: r

I found a similar question and response in Python ([identify records that make up 90% of total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682394/identify-records-that-make-up-90-of-total)) but couldn't quite translate it to R.

I'm trying to figure out the least number of products that make up at least 80% (this would be a variable since the % can change) of sales.

For example:

```
Product  Sales
A        100
B        40
C        10
D        15 
Total    165
```

The answer should be that I can get to 132 (80% of sales) by identifying two items.  The output should look like this:

```
Product  Sales
A        100
B        40
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a `dplyr` solution:
**Edit**:

Here a solution that seems to fit:

```
# your threshold
constant <- 0.5

data %>% 
# order
arrange(-Sales)%>% 
# add the cumulative
  mutate(cumulative = round(cumsum(Sales)/sum(Sales),2),
# add a threshold, the difference between the constant and the cumulative
         threshold = round(cumsum(Sales)/sum(Sales),2)- constant) %>%
# last, find all above the min value positive under the threshold
         filter(threshold <= min(.$threshold[.$threshold > 0]))

# for 0.8
  Product Sales cumulative threshold
1       A   100       0.61     -0.19
2       B    40       0.85      0.05

# for 0.5
  Product Sales cumulative threshold
1       A   100       0.61     -0.19
```

---

With data:

```
data <- read.table(text ="Product  Sales
A        100
B        40
C        10
D        15", header = T)
```

Comment: Very nice.  Almost there.  The criteria is when the sales hit or cross 80%.  I only see product A when I change the 85% to 80%...  What can I change to your solution?

Comment: The criteria is when the sales hit or cross 80%. I only see product A when I change the 85% to 80%... What can I change to your solution?

Comment: My solution is going to order the product and fetch the least number that provides at least the 80%. If you try with a wider dataset, the result is the same. Sorry I do not understand this comments, but feel free to add more question to clarify.

Comment: When I enter .5 I get no records instead of product A.  Hmm. Do you know why?  Thanks again!!

Comment: I guess I can just enter a statement to give me the 1st product if no records are returned since it's cumulative is greater than the criteria?

Comment: You can simplify it to  
`data %>% filter(round(cumsum(Sales)/sum(Sales), 1) <= 0.8)`.

Comment: Thanks @s_t.  The only issue is that this is going to be dynamic.  I won't always know what the cumulative % is for the top item.   I don't want to have to worry and make sure that the threshold % is at least the cumulative % for the top item.

Comment: Is there a way to say to take the top product if there are no results.  For example, a 50% filter shows no records because the top product has a cumulative of 60%.  So in that case it would just show product A...

Comment: Very very nice.  It's giving me the right combinations for all scenarios.  I will take a closer look at what you did so I can fully understand it.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

s_t answer is simple and efficient but if you are looking for a base R solution and a function:

```
example <- data.frame(Product = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Sales = c(100, 40, 10, 15))

min.products <- function(Product, Sales, percent){
  df <- data.frame(Product, Sales)
  minimum <- percent*sum(df$Sales)
  df <- df[order(-df$Sales), ]
  lowest.score <- df$Sales[cumsum(df$Sales)>minimum][1]
  answer <- df$Product[df$Sales>=lowest.score]
  return(answer)
}
min.products(example$Product, example$Sales, 0.8)
```

Comment: If I enter a criteria of 91% ($150.15) it selects item A B C (total sales of $150).  Not quite $150.  Any changes to the code above that can resolve the issue?  Thanks.

Comment: I edited now, I had a mistake in the function that was referencing the object "example" and not the function call to the object "df". It should work now