# return customer top products that comprise 80% of their total volume

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Access, I have a table called'cust_demand' with field names customer ID (str), product ID (str), and demand (int).  I'm trying  to create a query (or set of queries) that will return a list of the largest products that comprise 80% of the customers volume.

I'm new to this forum, so don't have ability to paste an image of the tables to show sample input and desired output. so let me try and add some clarity in words.

I'm essentially trying to perform a Pareto analysis on my customer demand set.  By "largest" products, I mean the products with the highest demand; and, in effect, this would mean I'm looking for the shortest list of products that comprise 80% of the customers demand.

As further clarity, if the 7 largest products comprise 79% of their demand, and the top 8 products comprise 85% of their demand I would like to return the list of 8 products.

Also, if, say, the top 5 products comprise exactly 80% of their demand, and the 5th and 6th largest products have exactly the same demand, then the returned list should just return either the 5th or 6th product, not both, and it's not important which one returns.

I found this post [regarding how to do it in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893183/identify-products-that-make-up-80-of-total). But not sure how to translate this to Access or SQL.  Maybe i have to learn python...

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I don't know what YOU mean by "a list of the largest products that comprise 80% of the customers volume".

Comment: Will, you can have different lists comprising 80% of customers volume. Do you mean the smallest list of products that comprises 80% of cust volume?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, and thanks for you quick responses.  Hopefully my notes add necessary detail.

Comment: I think that the question is clear - he is looking for top products which create 80% of demand.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you want to get products that create top 80 percents from all products. Lets have a table like this:

[image]

This would be your query:

```sql
    SELECT p.Product,  p.Cust_demand, (SELECT SUM(Cust_demand) FROM Products as p1 WHERE p.Cust_demand <=p1.Cust_demand) AS SumUpToHere,
    (SELECT SUM(Cust_demand) FROM Products as p1 WHERE p.Cust_demand <=p1.Cust_demand) / (SELECT SUM(Cust_demand) FROM Products as p2) * 100  as PercentUpToHere
    FROM Products as p
    WHERE (SELECT SUM(Cust_demand) FROM Products as p1 WHERE p.Cust_demand <=p1.Cust_demand) / (SELECT SUM(Cust_demand) FROM Products as p2) * 100 <=80
    ORDER BY p.Cust_demand DESC;
```

to get result like this:
[image]

Only problem would be if you had 2 products on the top which have exact the same demand. This would ether show them or not - depends on where they are in the sorted list.

If you do not care about the Sums this is your query:

```sql
SELECT p.Product,  p.Cust_demand
FROM Products as p
WHERE 
       (SELECT SUM(Cust_demand) FROM Products as p1 WHERE p.Cust_demand <=p1.Cust_demand) 
       / (SELECT SUM(Cust_demand) FROM Products as p2) * 100 <=80
ORDER BY p.Cust_demand DESC;
```

[image]

Comment: Vlado, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!  (my upvote won't register because I'm new, so wanted to let you know).

Comment: @Will Dunlap: If this answer helped you please remember to upvote or mark as the answer.